# Scroll wheel scrolls in both directions

Tags: fedora, mouse, scrolling

I am using Fedora 25 on my laptop and have a weird problem with the wheel on my wireless mouse. Under the mouse is written Easterntimes Tech X-08, but Amazon says that  it is a Patuoxun mouse.

When I scroll down (let's assume it's a long page), it first scrolls up, and then down as I wanted. If i scroll slow, it barely moves (because it's scrolling up and then down).

I don't have this problem with that mouse on Windows.

What should I do?

Comment: If I am right, I saw similar problem with my Fedora and specific mouse (I though it was hardware problem). I have many different mouses and they work perfectly fine. Probably it is some problem in the driver. Without info about the mouse it is impossible to help.

Comment: it's a Easterntimes Tech X-08 (amazon says Patuoxun) mouse